# Manipulating a CSV File using Pandas: Identifying a value in a column and using data from other columns of the same row

Tags: python, pandas, csv, quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading

Using Pandas, I have created two columns in addition to the OHLC columns, in a CSV file. This is how the data frame looks like:

```
              Date   Close      ...          Return  bullishSignal
Symbol                          ...                               
SPY     2010-01-01  111.44      ...             NaN          False
SPY     2010-01-04  113.33      ...             NaN          False
SPY     2010-01-25  109.77      ...        0.017582          False
SPY     2010-01-26  109.31      ...       -0.000915          False
SPY     2010-01-27  109.83      ...       -0.000546           True
SPY     2010-01-28  108.57      ...        0.006816          False
SPY     2010-01-29  107.39      ...        0.022721          False
```

My objective is to calculate the 2 day return from the date ( Day 0 ) that the bullish signal occurs: ( Close (Day 2) - Open (Day 1) ) / Open ( Day 1 ).
Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move to pandas. Then you can transpose row-1 with the command `.shift(1)` and row+1 with the command `.shift(-1)`.

```
   x1                   # Original df
0   0
1   1 
2   2
3   3
4   4 

df.x2 = df.x1.shift(1)  # Shift down

   x1  x2
0   0 NaN
1   1   0
2   2   1
3   3   2
4   4   3


df.x2 = df.x1.shift(-1)  # Shift up

   x1  x2
0   0   1
1   1   2
2   2   3
3   3   4
4   4   NaN
```

Applying `shift()`, you get all relevant values to one row and then just can apply column-wise operations:

```
from __future__ import division
df['Close_Next_Day']  = df['Close'].shift(-1)
df = df[df.bullishSignal == True] # Filter to bullish 
df['2dayReturn_bullish'] = (df['Close_Next_Day'] - df['Open']) / df['Open'])
```

You can do the same by using pandas percentage change function.

Comment: Thanks. I did that to calculate the Returns column. Before applying what you are saying, I need to identify the date where the bullish signal was True, and then calculate the returns. I am having trouble identifying the dates and using the data from that point on. Any way to do that?

Comment: you're welcome. That being said, keep the look-ahead bias in mind. You can't sell for a days close because you don't know the close before closure. It is common practice to use next day's open (i.e. shift(-2))

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely be careful of that.